# Blob triggered Azure Function : Information about the failure message not found in webjobs-blobtrigger-poison queue even after maxDequeueCount

Tags: azure-functions

I have a blob triggered Azure function. I am trying to set up a fault tolerant for it.

As per the official docs, it's mentioned that:

> When a blob trigger function fails for a given blob, Azure Functions
> retries that function a total of five times by default. If all 5 tries
> fail, Azure Functions adds a message to a Storage queue named
> webjobs-blobtrigger-poison

I explicitly made my Azure function throw an exception. I get this message after the 5 retries:
`Message has reached MaxDequeueCount of 5. Moving message to queue 'webjobs-blobtrigger-poison'.`

But, when I check the storage account queue in the Azure Portal, I cannot find the failure message.

Can someone please help me understand what could be the reason behind it ?

I tried to throw an exception from my azure function in order to receive the failure message in the webjobs-blobtrigger-poison. But, no message is inserted.

Expected : After maxdequeuecount of 5, the failure message should be inserted to the webjobs-blobtrigger-poison queue.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried with Queue Trigger, I got the poison queue along with the messages.
[image]

When I have tried with the Blob Trigger, I got the below message:

> Message has reached MaxDequeueCount of 5. Moving message to queue ‘webjobs-blobtrigger-poison’

This issue is in open state in the  [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/28799).
Azure Customers also getting the same message when retry policy fails in the Azure Functions blob/Queue Trigger, but the failure message is not logging in the associated Storage Queue.
There is a  [workaround](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/21449#issuecomment-850851259)  given by Azure Support Team in similar issue of the GitHub. If it’s not solved the problem, comment on the GitHub Ticket 28799 with more information.